# Gradle Implementation vs API configuration

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, implementation

I'm trying to figure out what is the difference between `api` and `implementation` configuration while building my dependencies.

In the documentation, it says that `implementation` has better build time, but, seeing this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44231886/android-gradle-4-0-compile-dependency-deprecated-how-does-new-api-configuration#comment75475030_44231886) in a similar question I got to wonder if is it true.

I'm not an expert in Gradle. I've read the [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html) already but I was wondering about an easy-to-understand explanation.

Comment: Have you read [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/new-android-plugin-migration.html#new_configurations)?

Comment: as in matter of fact, I did, but, as I said, that comment made wonder about it. so I'm kinda lost now

Comment: You probably will switch your libraries dependencies from `compile` to `api`. The libraries you use internally could use some private implementations which is not exposed in the final library so they are transparent to you. Those "internal-private" dependencies can be switched to `implementation` and when Android gradle plugin will compile your app it will skip the compilation of those dependencies resulting in a smaller build time (but those dependencies will be available at runtime). Obviously you can do the same thing if you have local module libraries

Comment: So if I use implementation instead of compile for dependencies like v7 or any other library it is not supposed to work? because it is working as far as I tested (not that much)

Comment: No, i think i did not explained this really well. As a rule of thumb in one of the Google I/O 2017 video, one of the Google engineers suggested to change all the `compile` statement to `implementation`, and use `api` only if you see something not working. (I will search the video for your when i have time)

Comment: Here's a short graphical explanation of 'api' and 'implementation': https://jeroenmols.com/blog/2017/06/14/androidstudio3/

Comment: Reading Jeroen Mols blog helped me too. Basically if you're building an app, you won't expose the API so just use `implementation` in your apps. The difference is only there when developing libraries.

Comment: This one is also a good article: https://blog.gradle.org/incremental-compiler-avoidance

Comment: Actually, the real explanation is here -> https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#dependency_configurations

Answer (score 853, accepted):

Gradle `compile` keyword was deprecated in favor of the `api` and `implementation` keywords to configure dependencies.

Using `api` is the equivalent of using the deprecated `compile`, so if you replace all `compile` with `api` everything will works as always.

To understand the `implementation` keyword consider the following example.

**EXAMPLE**

Suppose you have a library called `MyLibrary` that internally uses another library called `InternalLibrary`. Something like this:

```
// 'InternalLibrary' module
public class InternalLibrary {
    public static String giveMeAString(){
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

```
// 'MyLibrary' module
public class MyLibrary {
    public String myString(){
        return InternalLibrary.giveMeAString();
    }
}
```

Suppose the `MyLibrary` `build.gradle` uses `api` configuration in `dependencies{}` like this:

```
dependencies {
    api(project(":InternalLibrary"))
}
```

You want to use `MyLibrary` in your code so in your app's `build.gradle` you add this dependency:

```
dependencies {
    implementation(project(":MyLibrary"))
}
```

Using the `api` configuration (or deprecated `compile`) you can access `InternalLibrary` in your application code:

```
// Access 'MyLibrary' (granted)
MyLibrary myLib = new MyLibrary();
System.out.println(myLib.myString());

// Can ALSO access the internal library too (but you shouldn't)
System.out.println(InternalLibrary.giveMeAString());
```

In this way the module `MyLibrary` is potentially "leaking" the internal implementation of something.  You shouldn't (be able to) use that because it's not directly imported by you.

The `implementation` configuration was introduced to prevent this.
So now if you use `implementation` instead of `api` in `MyLibrary`:

```
dependencies {
    implementation(project(":InternalLibrary"))
}
```

you won't be able to call `InternalLibrary.giveMeAString()` in your app code anymore.

This sort of boxing strategy allows Android Gradle plugin to know that if you edit something in `InternalLibrary`, it must only trigger the recompilation of `MyLibrary` and *not* the recompilation of your entire app, because you don't have access to `InternalLibrary`.

When you have a lot of nested dependencies this mechanism can speed up the build a lot. *(Watch the video linked at the end for a full understanding of this)*

**CONCLUSIONS**

- When you switch to the new Android Gradle plugin 3.X.X, you should replace all your `compile` with the `implementation` keyword **(1*)**. Then try to compile and test your app. If everything it's ok leave the code as is, if you have problems you probably have something wrong with your dependencies or you used something that now is private and not more accessible. *Suggestion by Android Gradle plugin engineer Jerome Dochez **(1*)***)
- If you are a library mantainer you should use `api` for every dependency which is needed for the public API of your library, while use `implementation` for test dependencies or dependencies which must not be used by the final users.

[Useful article](https://medium.com/mindorks/implementation-vs-api-in-gradle-3-0-494c817a6fa) Showcasing the difference between **implementation** and **api**

**REFERENCES**
(This is the same video splitted up for time saving)

[Google I/O 2017 - How speed up Gradle builds (FULL VIDEO)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ll-rkLCtyk)

[Google I/O 2017 - How speed up Gradle builds (NEW GRADLE PLUGIN 3.0.0 PART ONLY)](https://youtu.be/7ll-rkLCtyk?t=22m21s)

[Google I/O 2017 - How speed up Gradle builds (reference to **1***)](https://youtu.be/7ll-rkLCtyk?t=30m37s)

[Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/new-android-plugin-migration.html#new_configurations)

Comment: "Potentially a noob developer could have used the appcompat declared internally in your library instead of providing it's own dependency" Why would you declare the same dependency in multiple modules when all modules depend on a super module where you can define the dependency once?

Comment: I noticed that api doesn't seem to work well in library modules. If I use it, I still can't access the dependencies from my app project. I can only access the code in that library itself.

Comment: This is fine and works on debug-builds but when using ProGuard (on release-versions) `MyLibrary#myString()` will crash because ProGuard will have `InternalLibrary` removed. What's the best-practice for android-libs to be used in ProGuard'ed apps?

Comment: @hardysim you should use `api` for the dependencies imported in your library

Comment: @MatPag right, that's what I got when reading the docs (only in-project-modules should use implementation). But it would be way better to have this "app needs to import everything itself" for external libs as well. I think material-dialogs does this by providing a ProGuard-keep-class-rule to keep the libs it uses. This way the 3rd-party libs are not visible to the app but still working on runtime? Is this a good way?

Comment: I think the answer is not accurate, the application can use whatever scope it wants for the MyLibrary. It will see or not the InternalLibrary depending whether or not the MyLibrary uses api / implementation.

Comment: @Snicolas yes, i will clarify this updating the answer as soon as i have time to update it

Comment: @Snicolas I've updated my answer, can you check it if now is more clear?

Comment: that's a beautiful explanation.  Theory and concrete mixed brilliantly.  Well done.  Thanks for that

Comment: Great answer , but newbies (like me) may not distinguish between "library"  and "app" rightaway that is mentioned - here's a good link that they should read to better appreciate the answer- https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/library_vs_application.html

Comment: In mylibrary.aar [MyLibrary/build/outputs/aar/ mylibrary.aar] if I open this and check for InternalLibrary class files, i don't see them. Can somebody explain this?

Note: i have used ------->api project(':InternalLibrary')

Comment: I have a project with an old library that only works with "compile", not "api" or "implementation".

Comment: What about the equivalent for `testImplementation` ? Why is there no `testApi` ?

Comment: @payne because tests are not included in the public API, it is always internal and is on the consuming end.

Comment: what about interfaces. 
suppose i have: 
 
`interface DeepInterface {}`. 

in deepMobule. 

Then i add this module to middleModule using api, define new interface in middleModule:  

`interface MiddleInterface : DeepInterface {}`. 

And finally i add middleModule to appModule using api or implementation (as i understand it doesn't matter for top module).   
The question is will i be able to use middleInterface in app module? (is not it leaking DeepInterface in this case?)

Comment: Do you meant that: If I set 'api(project(":InternalLibrary"))' in MyLibrary, the compiled file of MyLibrary (.aar file) should contain source code of InternalLibrary.  If I set 'implementation(project(":InternalLibrary"))', the MyLibrary's compiled file should not contain source code of ":InternalLibrary"?

Answer (score 302):

I like to think about an `api` dependency as **public** (seen by other modules) while `implementation` dependency as **private** (only seen by this module).

Note, that unlike `public`/`private` variables and methods, `api`/`implementation` dependencies are not enforced by the runtime. This is merely a build-time optimization, that allows `Gradle` to know which modules it needs to recompile when one of the dependencies changes its API.

Comment: The real difference (AFAICT) is that the generated pom file puts `api` dependencies in "compile" scope (they will be included as dependencies in your library and anything that depends on your library) and `implementation` dependencies in "runtime" scope (they better be on the classpath when your code is running, but they aren't needed to compile other code that uses your library).

Comment: @ShadowMan It's an implementation detail of the plugin, responsible for generating the POM file, how it maps **Gradle** scopes to **Maven** scopes.

Comment: You should use `implementation` for any dependency that is required to run (and for your library to compile), but that shouldn't be automagically pulled into projects that use your library. An example would be jax-rs, your library might use RESTeasy, but it shouldn't pull those libs into any project that uses your library, since they might want to use Jersey instead.

Answer (score 72):

Consider you have `app` module which uses `lib1` as a library and `lib1` uses `lib2` as a library. Something like this: `app -> lib1 -> lib2`.

Now when using `api lib2` in `lib1`, then `app` **can see** `lib2` code when using: `api lib1` or `implementation lib1` in the `app` module.

BUT when using `implementation lib2` in `lib1`, then `app` **can not see** the `lib2` code.

Answer (score 19):

Please refer the link: [Android Studio Dependency Configuration](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#dependency_configurations) available at android developers' official site.

Inside the dependencies block, you can declare a library dependency using one of several different dependency configurations (such as implementation shown above). Each dependency configuration provides Gradle with different instructions about how to use the dependency.

### implementation

Gradle adds the dependency to the compile classpath and packages the dependency to the build output. However, when your module configures an implementation dependency, it's letting Gradle know that you do not want the module to leak the dependency to other modules at compile time. That is, the dependency is available to other modules only at runtime.
Using this dependency configuration instead of api or compile (deprecated) can result in significant build time improvements because it reduces the number of modules that the build system needs to recompile. For example, if an implementation dependency changes its API, Gradle recompiles only that dependency and the modules that directly depend on it. Most app and test modules should use this configuration.

### api

Gradle adds the dependency to the compile classpath and build output. When a module includes an api dependency, it's letting Gradle know that the module wants to transitively export that dependency to other modules, so that it's available to them at both runtime and compile time.
This configuration behaves just like compile (which is now deprecated), but you should use it with caution and only with dependencies that you need to transitively export to other upstream consumers. That's because, if an api dependency changes its external API, Gradle recompiles all modules that have access to that dependency at compile time. So, having a large number of api dependencies can significantly increase build time. Unless you want to expose a dependency's API to a separate module, library modules should instead use implementation dependencies.

Answer (score 12):

One more technical note regarding `api` vs `implementation`. Suppose you have following dependencies:

```
dependencies {
  api "com.example:foo:1.0"
  implementation "com.example:bar:1.0"
}
```

If you install a generated jar file in your local Maven repository (with help of `maven-publish` plugin) you will see that generated `pom.xml` file will look like this:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.example</groupId>
      <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.example</groupId>
      <artifactId>bar</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Note: `api` was converted to `compile` scope and `implementation` - to `runtime` scope.

That allows for consumers of this library to avoid having runtime dependencies in their compile classpath.

Comment: Nice observation

Answer (score 11):

From [gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management_for_java_projects.html):

Let’s have a look at a very simple build script for a JVM-based project.

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:3.6.7.Final'
    api 'com.google.guava:guava:23.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
}
```

> **implementation**
>
> The dependencies required to compile the production source of the project which are not part of the API exposed by the project. For example the project uses Hibernate for its internal persistence layer implementation.
>
> **api**
>
> The dependencies required to compile the production source of the project which are part of the API exposed by the project. For example the project uses Guava and exposes public interfaces with Guava classes in their method signatures.

Answer (score 8):

Answers from [@matpag](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2910520/matpag) and [@dev-bmax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4283005/dev-bmax) are clear enough to make people understand different usages between implementation and api. I just want to make an extra explaination from another angle, hopes to help for peoples that have the same question.

I created two projects for testing :

- **project A** as a java library project named 'frameworks-web-gradle-plugin' depends on 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.20.RELEASE'
- **project B** depends on project A by implementation 'com.example.frameworks.gradle:frameworks-web-gradle-plugin:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

***The dependencies hierarchy descripted above looks like:***

**[project-b]  -> [project-a]  -> [spring-boot-gradle-plugin]**

Then I tested following scenarios:

1. Make project A depends on 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.20.RELEASE' by **implementation** .

   Run `gradle dependencies` command in a terminal in poject B root dir，with following screenshot of output we can see that 'spring-boot-gradle-plugin' appears in runtimeClasspath dependencies tree, but not in compileClasspath's, I think that's exactly why we can't make use of library that declared using implementation, it just won't through compilation.

   [image]
2. Make project A depends on 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.20.RELEASE' by **api**

   Run `gradle dependencies` command in a terminal in poject B root dir again.
   Now 'spring-boot-gradle-plugin' appears both in compileClasspath and runtimeClasspath dependencies tree.

   [image]

A significant difference I noticed is that the dependency in producer/library project declared in implementation way won't appear in compileClasspath of consumer projects, so that we can't make use of corresponding lib in the consumer projects.

Answer (score 6):

Now there is good explanation in the [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_separation)

> The api configuration should be used to declare dependencies which are
> exported by the library API, whereas the implementation configuration
> should be used to declare dependencies which are internal to the
> component.