# Difference between 'api' and 'implementation' in android studio 3.0 gradle dependencies

Tags: android-studio-3.0, gradle-dependencies

Since android studio 3.0 when I build a project a new syntax `implementation` is by default added in gradle dependency section like below:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
```

We can also use `api` instead of `implementation` here like below:

```
api 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
```

What is actual difference between implementation and api really? when we should use what as usual?

Comment: Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44413952/gradle-implementation-vs-api-configuration

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle Implementation vs API configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44413952/gradle-implementation-vs-api-configuration)