# Library not adding its dependencies when used

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

I made a library, but when I tried to use it with `implementation 'com.example:mylibrary:1.3.0'` in my app's `build.gradle`, I keep getting an error saying the ConstraintLayout dependency (which the library uses but not the app) is not found. However it was explicitly defined in the library's `build.gradle` with `implementation`.

When I ran `gradlew app:dependencies` on the terminal, it shows that the library has no dependencies, even though it actually has 2. This seems to be the source of the problem, Gradle can't detect the dependencies of the library.

I didn't run into this problem for a while but when I decided to remove the ConstraintLayout dependency from my app an error appears during build.

Answer (score 1):

When you're using `implementation` for the dependencies in your library, the project which is dependent with it will not see the dependencies. You need to use `api` instead of `implementation`.

Comment: Thanks, I thought `implementation` and `compile` were the same. More info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44419574/5288316

Comment: Actually this wasn't the problem, it was with the pom file not including the library's dependencies.