# Application can't use module's module

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have 1 app with 2 module

```
MyApp -> Framework -> Module
```

MyApp

```
implementation project(':Framework')
```

Framework

```
 implementation project(':MyModule')
```

But I can't use MyModule's files in MyApp. IDE show me "cannot access" error where I want to extend the class witch extend a MyModule class. And it not founds the classes from MyModule
Anyone have idea about this? What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `api` instead of `implementation` (in the middle module) if you want to provide access to the modules which are using it.

In your case, in the module `Framework`, use:

```
api project(':MyModule')
```

Comment: Read more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44413952/gradle-implementation-vs-api-configuration