# Proper use of 'implementation'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have a project with the following structure.

```
+-MyApplication
+-MyLibrayOne
+-MyLibrayTwo
```

`MyApplication` is my main application whereas `MyLibrayOne` and `MyLibrayTwo` are two libraries imported into project. `MyApplication` uses some classes of `MyLibrayOne` and `MyLibrayOne` uses some classes of `MyLibrayTwo`.

In the `.gradle` file of `MyLibrayOne` I have used `- compile project(':MyLibrayTwo')`. Everything works fine. But if I replace `compile` with `implementation` it can not import the classes from `MyLibrayTwo`. It gives `error: cannot find symbol class XXXX` error.

Comment: You need to use `api`. See this post: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44413952/gradle-implementation-vs-api-configuration)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I encourage you to have a look here in the [Google I/O 2017](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ll-rkLCtyk&feature=youtu.be&t=22m40s).
compile and implementation are not the same thing.
compile lets the application access to all sub-dependencies that the sub-library has access to. This means that if MyLibrayOne depends on MyLibraryTwo and you need also access to the class from MyLibrarayTwo you'll have to direct gradle to expose the classes from MyLibrayTwo using the compile directive.
If this is not needed then implementation is enough.
I can only guess that your case is the former and so you'll need to keep using compile. Since compile is now deprecated use the api directive. They are the same.
Also, have a look here in the [gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html).

Comment: In my case MyLibrayOne uses classes from MyLibrayTwo, but MyLibrayTwo is independent - MyLibrayTwo doesn't use any class of MyLibrayOne. If I use 'compile' I get warning that - "Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'. It will be removed at the end of 2018"

Comment: opps - forgot to tell you. replace the compile with api. they should be the same. I'll edit the answer to better reflect this.

Comment: another good source for info about this is: [Implementation Vs Api in Android Gradle plugin 3.0](https://medium.com/mindorks/implementation-vs-api-in-gradle-3-0-494c817a6fa)

Answer (score 2):

Use `api` instead of `implementation` will solve your problem. I.e.

```
dependencies {
    // Enforce the runtime dependencies
    api project(':MyLibrayOne')
    api project(':MyLibrayTwo')
}
```

Simply to explain, `api` will let the depending project **see** all the classes of the depended projects but `implementation` cannot do this.