# Error while explicitly casting Android's RecyclerView's ViewHolder in Kotlin: 'This cast can never succeed'

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

In Android, I am working on a library to make implementation of `RecyclerView` easy. I also want that once a developer has added this library as a dependency in `app build.gradle`, adding `RecyclerView` dependency in `app build.gradle` shouldn't be required. This library will basically be like a wrapper on `RecyclerView`.

I handled the view part by inflating `RecyclerView` dynamically in the library. For `LayoutManager`, I created a class based on Factory Design Pattern, where the developer can choose which `LayoutManager` and configuration he wants. But I faced an issue when implementing `Adapter` and `ViewHolder` wrapper classes.

**Attempt #1**

```
open class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)
```

Error: Missing super type dependency (which meant `RecyclerView` dependency needs to be present in `app build.gradle`)

**Attempt #2**

```
class ViewHolder(view: View)
```

and wherever I was using it internally in the library, I tried casing it explicitly as `viewHolder as ViewHolder`
or
`adapter as RecyclerView.Adapter`

Error: This cast can never succeed.

**Please guide me regarding this, how can I achieve a 100% wrapper on `RecyclerView`?**

Answer (score 1):

Your library presumably depends on the RecyclerView library with the following line:

```
implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$version"
```

By using **implementation** you are *not* exposing this dependency to modules that depend on your library. Therefore, users of your ViewHolder class will not know about the RecyclerView.ViewHolder class and it causes the described error.

Try using **api** to propagate this dependency up the module chain:

```
api "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$version"
```

Read about the differences [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44419574/6151924) or [here](https://medium.com/mindorks/implementation-vs-api-in-gradle-3-0-494c817a6fa).

---

**Update**: You can create a wrapper class and hide the property using internal visibility:

```
open class ViewHolder(view: View) {
    internal val recyclerHolder = RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)
}
```

This is similar to solution #2 but instead of casting to RecyclerView.ViewHolder, you use the property.

Comment: Thank you for the informative answer. But, that's the deal. I want my lib's classes to fundamentally wrap Android's RecyclerViews's classes. To a developer it should appear as if he is using a replacement of RecyclerView classes. I can post the full library project to help more. Current version is at github.com/mumayank/airlocation

Comment: Alright, still not sure why you want to specifically hide the RecyclerView classes but you could keep using the implementation dependency then and use wrappers that have kotlin *internal* properties. See updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this way into make viewholder class.

```
class ItemViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
 constructor(itemView: View) : super(itemView){}
```

}