# Nested libraries aar file behavior

Tags: java, android, aar

We are facing problem while importing the aar file of a library (let's call it `library_2`) into another library (let's call it `library_1`). In addition, we need to import in the app project only library_1.aar file and make library_2 methods available at project level. What would it be the folders structure and the corresponding .gradle files?

Description of the problem in the image below:
[image]

Comment: I don't undestand the question. If you need both libraries place them in /lib folder and import them via gradle

Comment: I have added one image to explain better. Please have a look @NicolaGallazzi

Comment: I've updated the question with this details

Comment: okay @NicolaGallazzi

Comment: Any news on this? I'm facing the same problem

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `api` instead `implementation` for your **library_1**. First, add the following code to your library_1 project `build.gradle`:

```
allprojects {
   repositories {
      jcenter()
      flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
      }
   }
}
```

then in your library_1 module build.gradle, add the following code to your dependencies block (assuming you have add library_2 aar to library_1 libs folder):

```
dependencies {
  api(name:'library_2', ext:'aar')
}
```

Now, you can access the library_2 when using library_1 aar with the following dependencies block in your app module:

```
dependencies {
  api(name:'library_1', ext:'aar')
}
```

For more details about flat aar, read [How to manually include external aar package using new Gradle Android Build System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682847/how-to-manually-include-external-aar-package-using-new-gradle-android-build-syst).

For more details about the differences between compile, implementation, and api read [Gradle Implementation vs API configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44413952/gradle-implementation-vs-api-configuration)

Comment: Already done but m still facing the same issue. As per my understanding we need to call  dirs project(':library_1').file('libs') at project level that i have already done and able to access the classes of library_1 but m not able to understand how to call the code for library_2 because we can't set library_2 at project level so we need to set on library_1

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved above issue that you are facing. Please have a look below code and let see if it work for you.

In your app.gradle file add below dependecy:

```
implementation ('package.name.of.aar:modulethree-debug@aar') {
   transitive=true
}
```

Note: `modulethree-debug@aar` is aar file which you want to access in other module.

Comment: yes you need to add module lib path on project level gradle file.