# Unresolved reference: compileKotlin in build.gradle.kts

Tags: gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Kotlin project success build by build.gradle:

```
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

Nice.

But I need to change to **build.gradle.kts**:

```
 plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.2.10"
    id("application")
}

group = "com.myproject"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

application {
    mainClassName = "MainKt"
}

java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

val kotlinVer = "1.2.10"

dependencies {
    compile(kotlin(module = "stdlib-jre8", version = kotlinVer))
    implementation("com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7")
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0")
    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0")
    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")

}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

and now I get error:

```
Line 32: compileKotlin {
           ^ Unresolved reference: compileKotlin
```

Comment: I don't see the `kotlin` plugin in your build script. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html

Comment: @LaksithaRanasingha I updated my post. It not help.

Answer (score 47):

There's an issue in the Kotlin Gradle DSL that causes this.

https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl-samples/issues/1368

You will need to use the following workaround until it gets resolved.

```
tasks.withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

Comment: Any ideas on how to extend this task?  I want to create a custom task that compiles kotlin files.

Comment: Should import `KotlinCompile` first: `import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile`.

Answer (score 15):

Following official Kotlin documentation ([using Gradle part](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html)), I suggest to use such constructions in the build.gradle.kts:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    java
    kotlin("jvm") version ("1.3.21")
}
// repositories, dependencies, etc...
val compileKotlin: KotlinCompile by tasks
val compileTestKotlin: KotlinCompile by tasks

compileKotlin.kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin.kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't be there a difference between `compileTestKotlin` and `compileKotlin`.  Or maybe I'm missing sth?

Answer (score 9):

Use `withType` keyword:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    val kotlin = "1.3.61"
    kotlin("jvm") version kotlin apply false
}

subprojects {
    repositories { mavenCentral(); mavenLocal() }
    apply(plugin = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm")

    tasks {
        val java: String by project
        withType<KotlinCompile>{ 
            kotlinOptions { jvmTarget = java }; sourceCompatibility = java; targetCompatibility = java 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### unrelated:  `Unresolved reference: compile`

I was able to provide the dependency to `implementation()` instead of `compile()`

```
// build.grdle.kts
//...
dependencies {
//- compile("com.cloudbees:groovy-cps:1.22)
//+ implementation("com.cloudbees:groovy-cps:1.22)
    implementation("com.cloudbees:groovy-cps:1.22)
}
//...
```

this so post says `api` and `implementation` keywords are successors to the `compile` keyword
[Gradle Implementation vs API configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44413952/gradle-implementation-vs-api-configuration)

edit:google turned up this question for `Unresolved reference: compile`

Answer (score 0):

```
 plugins{
    id ("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")  //add this
  }
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?