# Could not resolve com.squareup.sqldelight:runtime:1.1.3

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, sqldelight

I tried to integrate sqldelight in my Multiplatform library project for Android/iOS but I'm having several unresolved dependency errors when syncing gradle.

> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':SharedCode@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.squareup.sqldelight:runtime:1.1.3.
>
> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':SharedCode@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.squareup.sqldelight:runtime-jvm:1.1.3.
>
> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':SharedCode@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.squareup.sqldelight:runtime:1.1.3.
>   ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':SharedCode@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.squareup.sqldelight:runtime-jvm:1.1.3.**

- Gradle version 5.1.1
- Gradle Plugin 3.4.0
- sqldelight 1.1.3

`enableFeaturePreview('GRADLE_METADATA')` is present in my settings.gradle

My project gradle file looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlin_version = '1.3.31'
        ktor_version = '1.2.1'
        ktor_json_version = '1.2.1'
        kotlinx_coroutines_version = '1.2.1'
        serialization_version = '0.11.0'
        sqldelight_version = '1.1.3'
        dokka_version = '0.9.16'
    }

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-serialization:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.dokka:dokka-android-gradle-plugin:$dokka_version"
        classpath "com.squareup.sqldelight:gradle-plugin:$sqldelight_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://kotlin.bintray.com/kotlinx" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    setDelete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

my SharedCode lib gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlinx-serialization'
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform'
apply plugin: 'com.squareup.sqldelight'

group = 'com.example.multiplatform'
version = '1.0'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Specify Kotlin/JVM stdlib dependency.
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7'
    implementation "com.squareup.sqldelight:runtime:1.1.3"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test'
    testImplementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit'

    androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test'
    androidTestImplementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit'

    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

kotlin {
    targets {
        final def iOSTarget = System.getenv('SDK_NAME')?.startsWith("iphoneos")  \
                           ? presets.iosArm64 : presets.iosX64

        fromPreset(iOSTarget, 'ios') {
            binaries {
                framework('SharedCode')
            }
        }

        fromPreset(presets.android, 'androidLib')
    }

    sourceSets {
        commonMain {
            dependencies {
                //HTTP
                implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-json:$ktor_json_version"
                implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization:$ktor_version"
                //Coroutines
                implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-common:$kotlinx_coroutines_version"
                //Kotlinx serialization
                implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime-common:$serialization_version"
                //sqldelight
                implementation "com.squareup.sqldelight:runtime:$sqldelight_version"
            }
        }

        androidLibMain {
            dependencies {
                //HTTP
                implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-json-jvm:$ktor_json_version"
                implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization-jvm:$ktor_version"
                //Coroutines
                implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$kotlinx_coroutines_version"
                //Kotlinx serialization
                implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime:$serialization_version"
                //sqldelight
                implementation "com.squareup.sqldelight:android-driver:$sqldelight_version"
            }
        }

        iosMain {
            dependencies {
                //HTTP
                implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-ios:$ktor_version"
                implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-json-native:$ktor_json_version"
                implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization-native:$ktor_version"
                //Coroutines
                implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-native:$kotlinx_coroutines_version"
                //kotlinx serialization
                implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime-native:$serialization_version"
                //sqldelight
                implementation "com.squareup.sqldelight:ios-driver:$sqldelight_version"
            }
        }
    }
}

sqldelight {
    MyApp {
        packageName = 'com.example.multiplatform'
    }
}

configurations {
    compileClasspath
}

task packForXCode(type: Sync) {
    final File frameworkDir = new File(buildDir, "xcode-frameworks")
    final String mode = project.findProperty("XCODE_CONFIGURATION")?.toUpperCase() ?: 'DEBUG'
    final def framework = kotlin.targets.ios.binaries.getFramework("SharedCode", mode)

    inputs.property "mode", mode
    dependsOn framework.linkTask

    from { framework.outputFile.parentFile }
    into frameworkDir

    doLast {
        new File(frameworkDir, 'gradlew').with {
            text = "#!/bin/bash\nexport 'JAVA_HOME=${System.getProperty("java.home")}'\ncd '${rootProject.rootDir}'\n./gradlew \$@\n"
            setExecutable(true)
        }
    }
}
tasks.build.dependsOn packForXCode
```

Comment: apply sqldelight plugin at the end of file move this code `apply plugin: 'com.squareup.sqldelight'` at the bottom of the file.

Comment: nope, the issue remains

Comment: I have this error too.
Gradle updated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was solved this problem.
First: Apply sqldelight plugin right to all project:

```
apply plugin: 'com.squareup.sqldelight'
sqldelight {
    MyDatabase {
        packageName = "ru.trendagent.database"
        sourceFolders = ["sqldelight"]
    }
}
```

In android section add:

```
packagingOptions {
        ...
        exclude 'META-INF/*.kotlin_module'
    }
```

remove all implementations of sqldelight from `CommonMain` section
add implementation to AndroidMain section:

```
implementation "com.squareup.sqldelight:android-driver:1.1.3" //DataBase
```

add implementation to iosMain section if need:

```
implementation "com.squareup.sqldelight:ios-driver:1.1.3"//DataBase
```

add Metadata settings to gradle to `settings.gradle` file:

```
enableFeaturePreview("GRADLE_METADATA") // IMPORTANT!
```

Fully clean gradle files, reset gradle wrapper and other.
Don't use kotlin 1.4.0. It unsupport sqldelight 1.1.3 version
Change gradle to latest version. You can download latest gradle manually and set it on IDE. You need gradle 5.3.1 or latest (5.1.1 unsupported)

If error will remain - change IDE to intellij idea comunity edition

Answer (score 2):

This is seems to me as an error occurred due to offline gradle or invalid cache as this error is not specific to com.squareup.sqldelight. To resolve this issue follow the following steps:

- File
- Settings
- Build, Execution, Deployment
- Gradle
- Uncheck offline work

and then try to invalidate the cache and restart from file menu. Hope it helps!

Comment: @SlyBeaver Can you post your "gradle build --scan" report here

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
 classpath "com.squareup.sqldelight:gradle-plugin:$sqldelight_version"
```

Following

```
 classpath "com.squareup.sqldelight:runtime:$sqldelight_version"
```

you are passing wrong metadata to `sqldelight` change with my solution it will work

Comment: Replacing the line, I have a new error `Plugin with id 'com.squareup.sqldelight' not found.` And with the two classpath, the issue remains

Comment: you are adding this in wrong gradle file
you have to add this in your app folder gradle file 
with implementation "com.squareup.sqldelight:runtime:$sqldelight_version"

Answer (score 0):

The [Gradle](https://github.com/square/sqldelight#gradle) part of the readme of the library indicates, that gradle plugin is needed. There's no such  *sqldelight* library as *runtime*. They only have *android-driver*, *ios-driver* and *sqlite-driver*.

Comment: If I remove all the occurrences of *sqldelight runtime*, the issue is still here

Answer (score 0):

Using the [DroidConKotlin app project](https://github.com/touchlab/DroidconKotlin) as an example, I upgraded gradle from 5.1.1 to 5.3.1 and it resolved all the dependencies issues.

Comment: did you add `enableFeaturePreview('GRADLE_METADATA')` in your settings.gradle ? As advised in the readme of the sqldelight github, I now only import the ios-driver, the android-driver libs and apply the sqldelight plugin. No runtime, runtime-jvm or runtime-metadata lib.

Answer (score 0):

You likely are trying to use a dependency on dependant libraries or even applications and not only in commonMain module. Just change:

```
commonMain {
    dependencies {
        ...
        implementation "com.squareup.sqldelight:runtime:$sqldelight_version"
    }
}
```

to

```
commonMain {
    dependencies {
        ...
        api "com.squareup.sqldelight:runtime:$sqldelight_version"
    }
}
```

Also change it on **dependencies** section

And do the same with any other dependency uncorrecly resolved

This can happen for example if you define a class that implements an interface provided by the dependency and you use or extend that class on dependant libraries or applications (Just an example of millions that could be).

If this is your case, for further understanding, just take a look to  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44413952/gradle-implementation-vs-api-configuration):