# How to create a transitive hierarchical multi-project in Gradle?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have been using Gradle for some time now but have never delved deeper into it's many features and functionalities, but the other day I decided to split my Java project into two modules for easier testing and maintenance. After I was done I started reading about [Authoring Multi-projects](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html) and one of the newer Gradle concepts called [Composite builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html). Then I proceeded to spend the better part of the day trying to apply (what I thought I understood) this knowledge on making my project modular. It's safe to assume that I was not successful and now here I am asking for help in understanding these concepts and their application.

#### Theoretical Workspace

Let us imagine that we have the following directory structure:

```
toolbox
|
├── first-tool
|   └── build.gradle
|
├── second-tool
|   └── build.gradle
|
├── build.gradle
└── settings.gradle
```

And these are the projects inside the root directory:

```
Root project 'toolbox'
+--- Project ':first-tool'
\--- Project ':second-tool'
```

Let's make project `first-tool` introduce an external dependency `org.master-toolbox:some.other.tool` on which the second toolbox is dependent on but does not implement itself:

```
default - Configuration for default artifacts.
+--- org.master-toolbox:some.other.tool:1.0
|    +--- ...
\--- io.toolbox:first-tool
```

These are the relevant Gradle files:

**settings.gradle**

```
rootProject.name = 'toolbox'

include 'first-tool', 'second-tool'
```

**toolbox.build.gradle**

```
allprojects {

    apply plugin: 'java-library'

    group = "io.toolbox"

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**first-tool.build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    // This is an external dependency that is resolved through jcentral
    implements 'org.master-toolbox:some.other.tool:1.0'
}
```

**second-tool.build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    // Try to implement first-tool build to inherit dependencies
    implementation 'io.toolbox:first-tool'
}
```

The above produces a nice project structure as shown above but would not fully work because `second-tool` would not find `first-tool` and something similar to the following error would appear in our console:

```
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':second-tool:compileClasspath'.
   > Could not find io.toolbox:first-tool:.
     Required by:
         project :second-tool
```

Now as far as I understand it this is where composite builds are suppose to swoop-in and save the day by allowing us to include entire builds. Well that sounds great, let us just update out `settings.gradle`:

```
rootProject.name = 'toolbox'

includeBuild `first-tool`
include 'second-tool'
```

Now the project builds and compiles properly, everything is good right? Well not exactly, as by using the `includeBuild` keyword in our `settings.gradle` `first-tool` is no longer inheriting properties from `toolbox` and has essentially stopped being a sub-project of `toolbox`.

#### Project Goal

I am most probably misunderstanding the whole concept of composite builds or just making silly mistakes. Either way what I would like to know is if there is any way to have a hierarchical multi-project structure with sub-projects that are interdependent upon each-other?

As it stands I have to choose between the following:

- a regular multi-project build where everything is neat and organized and all my sub-projects share the same definitions from the top project.
- a composite build where I am free to create inter-project dependencies.

It would be great if it was possible to have a main `build.gradle` that resides at the top project's root directory and defines the common plugins, repositories, group etc. for the whole hierarchy. Other projects would then have their own `build.gradle` files that would give them unique properties but would execute their tasks from the top project.

I have already read the official documentation on this subject so I am looking for more concrete explanations and directions on how to accomplish this specific goal.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44413952/gradle-implementation-vs-api-configuration

Comment: @Henry Thank you, I've already read that and am familiar with the difference between `api` and `implementation` keyword`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With multi-module builds, a module can depend on another module. To let the second project depend on the first, edit `second-tool/build.gradle` as:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':first-tool')
}
```

Also, the first module should probably be:

```
dependencies {
    api 'org.master-toolbox:some.other.tool:1.0'
}
```

---

You can use a multi-module build to do what you describe; you can have inter-module dependencies, and modules can be configured from the top-level build by using either `allprojects { ... }` or `subprojects{ ... }`.

Composite builds are rarely used- if you are happy with a "monolitic" build, and don't need to split your code into different repos. etc., then go with a (plain) multi-module build.

Comment: I've managed to solve this problem yesterday and the way I've done it is by making `second-tool` implement `first-tool` from `toolbox` (root project), but your way is actually better. Implementing it directly from the builds that actually need it makes more sense.