# Why ArCore dependecy don't work like transitive dependency?

Tags: android, android-ndk, dependencies, arcore, lib

I have created Android lib that uses ArCore (native) (https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/c/enable-arcore), one of the requirements is to add in your gradle file a few lines

This one `configurations { natives }` at the top of your gradle file and these

```
implementation 'com.google.ar:core:1.13.0'
natives 'com.google.ar:core:1.13.0'
```

at the dependencies block

I have added them in my Android lib. Then I build `.aar` file and added it to sample project to check if it is works as expected, and **I got an error** in this line

> CHECK(ArCoreApk_requestInstall(env, activity, user_requested_install, &install_status) == AR_SUCCESS);

In order to solve it I had to edit gradle file(add dependency above) of sample project and then it work.

Question is - why I need to add twice the same dependency under my lib gradle and my project gradle...

I thought that after I have add all required dependency in my lib I should not duplicate them also in project...

Comment: What's the error message you got?

Comment: @stewe93 but I wrote it in question...

Comment: You say "in this line" but this isn't an error message. Nevermind. Would you mind to try to add your ArCore devendencies with the `api` keyword instead of `implementation`? I think this would solve your issue. If it works I will answer the question if you don't mind.

Comment: hmm `api`, just now tried and look with usage of `api` in my sample project I don't need to write two lines as I described in question , but instead I need to write this line `api 'com.google.ar:core:1.13.0'`, I agree that it is less the two lines, but anyway question is - why I need to duplicate it (even with one line) if all of this dependency has already included in lib's gradle file... ? Or I did not get your idea?

Comment: In your own library, change the implementation to api than I think this would solve your problem

Comment: @stewe93 I found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44419574/5709159 and have already tried to change `implementation` to `api`, but it is not helped.