# why some projects import androidx.activity-ktx or not?

Tags: android, gradle

I started a new project and import previous dependency settings, And tried using by `viewModel` in activity. But I can't get the by `viewModel` reference, So I tried going to External libraries. The previous project has `androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.0.0` even though I didn't add `implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.0.0"`. you can see this happening at https://github.com/android/architecture-samples .

But When I try to start a new project and import setting from previous project, I can't get the
`androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.0.0`. I don't unserstand previous project or the sample of google import this  `androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.0.0` , and my new project do not import that. although the gradle setting and gradle version is same.

Answer (score 3):

Android KTX is a set of Kotlin extensions to help your write concise and idiomatic code.

`by viewModel` extension is not available by default for a new android project and should be added using Android KTX, particularly `androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:'version'`.

You may find other useful extensions you would like to add to project like
`androidx.activity:activity-ktx:`, `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:` etc. Each one adds some special "syntactic sugar" so don't hesitate to learn their possibilities.

Please, see reference [Android KTX](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx)

Comment: I understand why I have to add that two libraries. I'm saying I don't understand the example of google(what I linked) doesn't implement that two libraries, but have that two libraries

Comment: Why can't I use `by activityViewModels()` in my Activity?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky because this extension belongs to Fragment... You can use `by activityViewModels()` only inside a Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you can import previous dependency settings from other project into new project. Is it a function of Android Studio?

But I think print the whole dependency tree will solve your confusion, because **some dependencies maybe be implicit  included by directly declared dependencies**.

You can open terminal and execute `./gradlew dependencies` to print all dependencies of the whole project.

See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/viewing_debugging_dependencies.html for more details.

I tried and found this,

- Repo: https://github.com/android/architecture-samples
- Version: [d31721f](https://github.com/android/architecture-samples/commit/d31721fbc00d95e5007dd88bf4696350262be435)

```
debugRuntimeClasspath - Runtime classpath of compilation 'debug' (target  (androidJvm)).
+--- androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.1.1
|    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0 -> 1.3.
|    +--- androidx.compose.runtime:runtime:1.1.1
|    |
|    |
...
|    \--- androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.0 -> 1.4.0
|         +--- androidx.compose.runtime:runtime:1.0.1 -> 1.1.1 (*)
|         +--- androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-saveable:1.0.1 -> 1.1.1 (*)
|         +--- androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.4.0
...
```

It tells us that `androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.4.0` is imported by `androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.0`, and `androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.0` is imported by `androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.1.1`.

You can find the `androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.1.1` is declared in app's `build.gradle`. [Link](https://github.com/android/architecture-samples/blob/d31721fbc00d95e5007dd88bf4696350262be435/app/build.gradle#L152)

Then, you can find the `activity-compose` import `activity-ktx` by using **`api`** following this [link](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:activity/activity-compose/build.gradle;drc=87e3bd023b6dfe56d3262355011405cca4bea4d6;l=32).

> About the `api`'s meaning in `build.gradle`, please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44419574).

So project [*architecture-samples*](https://github.com/android/architecture-samples) can use `viewModels()` without `implementation` the dependency `activity-ktx` in `build.gradle`.