# Android dependency module

Tags: android, kotlin, module, dependencies, clean-architecture

I need to create separate module, in witch I will only have dependencies to another modules (app, wearOSApp, core). How can I get part of dependencies from this module, to another module? Did someone something similar and can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **api** instead of **implementation** in gradle for together dependencies, these become available for other modules. In app and wearOS module use implementation project(":core").

More details here https://stackoverflow.com/a/44419574/16552338.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, thank you