# How to add runtime requirement without bundling it with the application distributables?

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, google-play-services, licensing

I want to use [Firebase](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html?q=firebase#com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.3.0) and [Play services](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html?q=play-serv#com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1) libraries. As far as I understand it is ok to depend on this library and use it's functionality if it's already present on the device or require to download it, but due to the [licensing](https://developer.android.com/studio/terms) I can not distribute this libraries bundled with my application.

My question:
How do I declare dependency and have 100% certainty that it is **not bundled but will be provided** on the phone?

Before this way of adding classpath dependency in buildscript was sufficient for me and added dependencies only during compilation:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

But unfortunately now it has to be added to the application dependencies in [that way](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#add-sdks) (adding do buildscript doesn't work):

```
dependencies {
  implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.1.0')
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore'
}
```

I'm new to android development, but as explained [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#dependency_configurations), when we use different gradle dependency declarations we get:

> implementation
> Gradle adds the dependency to the compile classpath and **packages the dependency to the build output**.

> api
> Gradle adds the dependency to the compile classpath and **build output**.

> compileOnly
> Gradle adds the dependency to the compile classpath only (that is, it is **not added to the build output**). This is useful when you're creating an Android module and you need the dependency during compilation, but **it's optional to have it present at runtime**.

> runtimeOnly
> Gradle adds the dependency to the **build output** only, for use during runtime. That is, it is not added to the compile classpath.

Does `api` dependency solve my problem, as the description doesn't use the word `packages` ?

Comment: If I'm mistaken and I can freely distribute firebase/play libraries, I would need a solid reference with explanation

Comment: Unclear if you are looking for: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/overview and/or https://developers.google.com/android/guides/opensource Also read: [Gradle Implementation vs API configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44413952/295004)